# if mediaplayer.pasue() is called before mediaplayer.start() , then music is not playing

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-mediaplayer

i created two onClick methods for buttons Play and Pause but if tap on Pause first and then tap on Play button, The music is not playing. below is the code

```
package com.example.myaudio;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    public void playAudio(View view)
    {
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
    public void pauseAudio(View view)
    {

        if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
           mediaPlayer.pause();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.mymusic);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [the `MediaPlayer` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer) says, the only states in which it is valid to call `pause` are *Started*, *Paused*, and *PlaybackCompleted*.

Calling `pause` when in some other state puts the `MediaPlayer` instance in an *Error* state, and trying to `start` the `MediaPlayer` when it is in an *Error* state will not work.

Bottom line: don't call methods on a `MediaPlayer` unless the player is in a state in which it is ok to call that method (as described by the documentation).

Comment: how to handle the Error State,so i could playing the Music on clicking Start button

Comment: You would have to call `reset` and then prepare the player again. But that sounds like the wrong way to solve the problem. You should avoid getting to an _Error_ state in the first place, by not calling `pause` except when it's ok to do so.